# WCF published to Azure Cloud Service is unreachable

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, azure-cloud-services

When I run the WCF on my computer it works like expected, but when I publish it ( from the VS 2013) I cant access it.

When I try :

> http://myWCF.cloudapp.net/Service.svc

or

> http://myWCF.cloudapp.net

I get

```
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
```

This is my web.config file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Storage" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol" />
    <add name="DB" connectionString="Server=tcplient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
      <listeners>
        <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
          name="AzureDiagnostics">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
    -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Maybe the pre configure remote desktop is doing the problems ?

Any idea why its happens ? What cause it ?

**Update**

After publishing its works as expected (good) but after I connect to the service with Remote Desktop Connection and installed my software upon the machine I get the

> No HTTP resource...

Additnial info:

This is the csdef file: (with the endpoints)

```
    <ServiceDefinition name="FilteringServiceAzureWCF" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2014-06.2.4">
  <WebRole name="WCFFilteringService" vmsize="Small">
    <Runtime executionContext="elevated" />
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
    </Endpoints>
    <ConfigurationSettings>
    </ConfigurationSettings>
    <Imports>
      <Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />
      <Import moduleName="RemoteForwarder" />
    </Imports>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

Comment: Did you check that the endpoint for port 80 is open for the VM or Cloud Service?

Comment: I updated my original post @SimonW.

Comment: I would recommend for you to host your WCF service in a worker role cloud service this way with manual configuration you will sure to have access to your service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your port 80 is not occupied by any other program on your machine.

WCF uses port 80 by default, however you can define a different port on the csdef file.